# Construct matrix from array indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

This is probably very simple but I cannot see it. Is there any way to construct the matrix B (below) without enumerating over all A(i)?

```
A = [0 0 1 2 0 1];
>> B = [A == A(1);A == A(2);A == A(3);A == A(4);A == A(5);A == A(6)]

B =

 1     1     0     0     1     0
 1     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1
 0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
bsxfun(@eq,A(:),A)
```

On MATLAB 2016b onwards with automatic broadcasting, it would simplify to -

```
A(:)==A
```

Looks like some ascii art there, probably if it were `B`!